# How can I obtain a license to use Bing images?

Tags: licensing, stock-photography

I want to create a Facebook page for my local church and I would like to use some of the images featured on Bing.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what you mean by "the Bing images"? Are you talking about the Bing "Image of the day" that is displayed as a background whenever you go to bing.com?

Answer (score 5):

Bing do not host neither own copyright of images it display. You should go to the page which host the image, talk to the owner if this is personal web site and/or check if the image is from stock agency or it is owned by the web site owner. Or buy the image if this is image stock agency.

Comment: Assuming they mean the image of the day, I can't see an obvious place where the owner's information is present. Can you elaborate on how one would figure out who the image owner is?

Comment: @trlkly, what I mean (mainly) is the image search engine of Bing

Comment: @trlkly, In MSN site, articles, you can see the author and agency below the image

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps as an alternative to using Bing or Google images, you could access a site specifically geared to providing royalty free images such as [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com), [Pexels](https://www.pexels.com/royalty-free-images/) or [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com) (there are others). Some of these sites also provide images for a price, but there are lots of free content. There is also [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) which is entirely free.